# How to disable bottom SafeArea in child widget or change it's color?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to disable SafeArea at the bottom inside a child widget?

If I have something like:

```
SafeArea(
   child: SecondWidget(),
)
```

Is there a possibility to disable bottom part of the SafeArea in SecondWidget()? Or is there a way to set up background color only for the bottom part of the SafeArea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. [SafeArea](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html) has a [bottom](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea/bottom.html) property to ignore system intrusions in the bottom part of the screen. I would use it like this:

```
SafeArea(
   child: SecondWidget(),
   bottom: false
)
```